# ThreadPool size dynamic

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot

Currently I have my thread pool size fixed from the properties file. I need it to be dynamic based on the DAO call List size.

How can I do it?

```
private static ScheduledExecutorService threadPool;

@Value("${project.threadPoolSize}")
public void setThreadPool(Integer poolSize) {
    threadPool = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(poolSize);
}
@PostConstruct
public void Master(){
  List processes = DAOCall.processes();
  int List_size = processes.size();
}
```

I need my thread pool size to be the size of processes. When I'm doing it like

```
private static ScheduledExecutorService threadPool;
@PostConstruct
public void Master(){
  List processes = DAOCall.processes();
  int List_size = processes.size();
  threadPool = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(List_size );
}
```

My DAO Call gives 0, and its not working.

how to achhieve this ?

Comment: thread pool size is configuration which define at program startup, you need JMX to change configurations

Comment: Do you need the pool to be a scheduled one? Regular pools can have a dynamic number of threads out-of-the-box

Comment: @Dici yes the pool need to be a scheduled one.